# Ansible passwordless access between nodes

Tags: ansible

To give passwordless access to all nodes for all other nodes.

```
For each node:   
  Get public ssh key   
  Add that key to authorized_keys files of all other nodes
```

Below is what I tried, but it's not working as expected.

```
- name: Get ssh public key from all the nodes for some_user user
  shell: cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
  register: ssh_pub_key
  become: yes
  become_user: some_user
  changed_when: "ssh_pub_key.rc != 0"
  always_run: yes

- set_fact:
    auth_keys: "{{ ssh_pub_key.stdout | join() }}"

- debug: var=auth_keys

- name: Add public key to all other nodes for some_user user
  authorized_key:
    user: some_user
    key: "{{ ssh_pub_key.stdout }}"
```

Comment: Try collecting public key and `set_fact` for each node, then apply a template  with some looping through [magic variables](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts) inside it.

Answer (score 2):

No need to collect every ssh keys from every node and distribute them to every node, this is bad practice.

Use ssh agent forwarding instead.

All you need is one key (create it onto central server or use existing one) and simply push pub (by ansible) to your nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Clone the repository to your ansible-enabled host:

```
git clone https://github.com/ilias-sp/ansible-setup-passwordless-ssh.git
```

Alternatively, you can download the ansible_setup_passwordless_ssh.yml and hosts from this repository.

run:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts ansible_setup_passwordless_ssh.yml
```

By running this playbook, these things happen to your hosts:

Localhost: An SSH key is generated and placed under .ssh folder. Its file name is configurable, default is ansible_rsa. This SSH key is added to the ~/.ssh/config file for SSH client to utilize it when connecting to remote hosts.

Remote hosts: The generated SSH key is propagated to the list of remote hosts you configured in hosts inventory file, and added to their ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file. This is done using the ssh-copy-id linux utility that is meant for this job. sshpass linux utility is used to assist running the script without the need to prompt for user password.

Reference : https://github.com/ilias-sp/ansible-setup-passwordless-ssh